# How do I get my MacOS X terminal key mappings fully in sync with my Windows XP key mappings?

Tags: mac, keyboard-shortcuts, terminal, cygwin

I have a Windows laptop at work, running cygwin.
I'm very comfortable with its key mappings.

My ideal setup would be for my Terminal app on my Mac home computer to have the same key mappings.  It's not just a matter of copying over my .zshrc and xmodmap settings.

And it's not just a mapping of switching the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and <kbd>Cmd</kbd> keys, system-wide (which I've already done).

Is there any generic way to have the two keymappings be identical?

Comment: It would probably help if you gave a concrete example of some keys that don't behave the way you would like.

Answer (score 1):

Your asking for a generic way, but the problem you have is that you:

- don't use one keyboard to control both computers (which would have a solution)
- don't have the same operation system (which reduces the chance of a generic solution)

To remap your Mac keyboard you can use something like [Controllermate](http://orderedbytes.com/controllermate/newfeatures/) or run [AutoHotKey](http://www.autohotkey.com/) (using Darwine is claimed to work) to map special functions to your keys.

If you want to change your Windows keyboard use [Microsoft Keyboard Layout Creator 1.4](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=8be579aa-780d-4253-9e0a-e17e51db2223&DisplayLang=en).

It's too bad AutoHotKey needs the Windows API so much, but if it works with Darwine, that should already do the trick for you.

Edit: Check this program too [Double Command](http://doublecommand.sourceforge.net/) and if anyone can find the question about controlling multiple computers with one keyboard/mouse please leave a comment

Comment: actually I do use the same keyboard for both my Mac and my windows laptop.  It's a Logitech keyboard.

Comment: I'll look up the previous question, though it's not entirely the way I meaned it. It was a question about controlling two computers (at the same time) with one keyboard

Answer (score 0):

You can customize the keyboard map in Terminal preferences:

> **Terminal > Preferences > Settings > [profile] > Keyboard**